# ¿Se pueden devolver las coordenas de un punto en una sola funcion?

Tags: c++, poo, clase, objeto

estoy empezando a aprender clases y he tenido una pregunta. He creado la clase Figura y dentro de ella he añadido una funcion para establecer el centro `setCenter(float x, float y)` y otra para que me devuelva el centro `getCenter()`. Para implementar esta última función, ¿sería posible hacerlo así?

```
float getCenter(){
   return x, y;
}
```

Mi duda realmente es si se pueden devolver dos parametros a la vez o si debería hacer una funcion para conseguir la X y otra para conseguir la Y.

Es ese caso entinedo que sería así:

```
float getX(){
    return x;
}
```

```
float getY(){
    return y;
}
```

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ¿Se pueden devolver las coordenadas de un punto en una sola función?

Si.

---

Crea un objeto punto:

```
struct Punto { float x{}, y{}; };
```

Entonces tendrás las siguientes opciones para devolver un punto:

1. Devolviendo un objeto `Punto` construido al vuelo:

   ```
   Punto getCenter(){
      return {x, y};
   }
   ```
2. Devolviendo un objeto `Punto` explícito construido al vuelo:

   ```
   Punto getCenter(){
      return Punto{x, y};
   }
   ```
3. Construyendo objeto `Punto` temporal y devolviéndolo:

   ```
   Punto getCenter(){
      Punto temporal{x, y}
      return temporal;
   }
   ```

Para leer los datos devueltos tendrás las siguientes opciones:

1. Alargando la vida del temporal:

   ```
   const Punto &centro = getCenter();
   ```
2. Copiando el valor devuelto:

   ```
   Punto centro = getCenter();
   ```
3. Leyendo cada componente por separado:

   ```
   auto [x, y] = getCenter();
   ```

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta de @PaperBirdMaster está completa.  Quisiera agregar algo más (aún no puedo agregar comentarios, así que añádelo a la respuesta de @PaperBirdMaster)

La respuesta 3 requiere vínculos estructurados (novedad en C++17)

4. Devolviendo una tupla:

```
std::tuple<float, float> Figura::getCenter() {
  return std::make_tuple(x, y);
}

...

// captura en variables usando std::tie:
Figura figura;

...

float a, b;
std::tie(a,b) = figura.getCenter();
```